# Azure DevTest Lab VM doesn't show up while configuring backup in Azure Recovery Vault

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-devtest-labs, azure-backup-vault

I've created a VM in an Azure DevTest Lab that -

- sits in a virtual network that uses a network security group with
  inbound and outbound rules. This enables only a selected set of users
  to be able to RDP to this VM.
- location is Australia Southeast

I'm now configuring a Recovery Vault in Central US. I've created backup policies and now I'm configuring backups.

1. Click '+ Backup'
2. In the 'Backup goal' screen, I've stuck with the defaults
3. Click 'Configure backup' button
4. In the 'Backup policy' screen, I've selected the policy I've
   created
5. However, in 'Items to backup', I'm not seeing any VMs (screenshot
   below)

[image]

I've already followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare#explicitly-allow-outbound-access) to add outbound rules to the NSG I created. I've also checked that the backup agent is installed in the VM. No luck in either approach.

Any idea what else would need to be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only backup virtual machines in the same region as your Recovery Services Vault.

You will need to:

- Move your VM to Central US
- Create a new Backup Vault in Australia South East
- Use a vault in Australia South East and configure storage replication to Central US

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare for requirements.